# How to execute install file in magento shop?

Tags: magento-1.9, database, extensions, installation

My module has been installed but no the tables. There is any issue with my install file

```
<?php
Mage::log('Installation du module Ns_Thorleif version 1.0.0', Zend_Log::INFO);

$this->startSetup();
if ($this->getConnection()->isTableExists($this->getTable('thorleif/commerciaux'))) {
    $this->getConnection()->dropTable($this->getTable('thorleif/commerciaux'));
}

$table = $this->getConnection()
    ->newTable($this->getTable('thorleif/commerciaux'))
    ->addColumn('id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_BIGINT, null, array(
        'identity'  => true,
        'nullable'  => false,
        'primary'   => true
    ), 'id')
    ->addColumn('name', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT, 255, array(
        'nullable'  => false), 'name')
    ->addColumn('city', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT, 255, array(
        'nullable' => false), 'city');

$this->getConnection()->createTable($table);

//*********Create Brand Table*************
if ($this->getConnection()->isTableExists($this->getTable('thorleif/brand'))) {
    $this->getConnection()->dropTable($this->getTable('thorleif/brand'));
}

$table = $this->getConnection()
    ->newTable($this->getTable('thorleif/brand'))
    ->addColumn('brandId', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_BIGINT, null, array(
        'identity'  => true,
        'nullable'  => false,
        'primary'   => true
    ), 'brandId')
    ->addColumn('name', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT, 255, array(
        'nullable'  => false), 'name');        

$this->getConnection()->createTable($table);

//************Create Category Table**********
if ($this->getConnection()->isTableExists($this->getTable('thorleif/category'))) {
    $this->getConnection()->dropTable($this->getTable('thorleif/category'));
}

$table = $this->getConnection()
    ->newTable($this->getTable('thorleif/category'))
    ->addColumn('id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_BIGINT, null, array(
        'identity'  => true,
        'nullable'  => false,
        'primary'   => true
    ), 'id')
    ->addColumn('id_linio_category', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT, 255, array(
        'nullable'  => false), 'id_linio_category')
    ->addColumn('name', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT, 255, array(
        'nullable'  => false), 'name')
    ->addColumn('level', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT, 255, array(
        'nullable'  => false), 'level');        

$this->getConnection()->createTable($table);

//************Create Credential Table**********
if ($this->getConnection()->isTableExists($this->getTable('thorleif/commercial'))) {
    $this->getConnection()->dropTable($this->getTable('thorleif/commercial'));
}

$table = $this->getConnection()
    ->newTable($this->getTable('thorleif/commercial'))
    ->addColumn('ID', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_BIGINT, null, array(
        'identity'  => true,
        'nullable'  => false,
        'primary'   => true
    ), 'ID')
    ->addColumn('Country', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT, 255, array(
        'nullable'  => false), 'Country')
    ->addColumn('Email', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT, 255, array(
        'nullable'  => false), 'Email')
    ->addColumn('Api', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT, 255, array(
        'nullable'  => false), 'Api')
    ->addColumn('Tax', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT, 255, array(
        'nullable'  => false), 'Tax')
    ->addColumn('Warranty', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT, 255, array(
        'nullable'  => false), 'Warranty');

//************Create Mapping Table**********
if ($this->getConnection()->isTableExists($this->getTable('thorleif/mapping'))) {
    $this->getConnection()->dropTable($this->getTable('thorleif/mapping'));
}

$table = $this->getConnection()
    ->newTable($this->getTable('thorleif/mapping'))
    ->addColumn('id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_BIGINT, null, array(
        'identity'  => true,
        'nullable'  => false,
        'primary'   => true
    ), 'id')
    ->addColumn('id_mapping', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT, 255, array(
        'nullable'  => false), 'id_mapping');

$this->getConnection()->createTable($table);

$this->endSetup();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have copied all files to there propper place ...

- app/etc/modules/Your_Module.xml
- app/code/POOL/Your/Module/... _(POOL is set in Your_Module.xml)
- flush cache to load your `config.xml`

If all files are in correct place you'll see your extension under "system - config - advanced - disable module output". If not check that you have copied all correctly a second time.

Recommendation:

- create a `modman` and `composer.json` file
- host your code at bitbucket or github
- install it via `modman clone PATH` or `composer require your/module`

Fore debugging if your extension is correctly loaded you can also try [FireGento_Debug](https://github.com/firegento/firegento-debug)

---

Helpful (?) links:

- http://alanstorm.com/php_composer_magento_tutorial/
- http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/how-to-make-magento-extensions-work-with-composer/

---

**Edit:**

To run your setup script

- put it in `app/code/POOL/Your/Module/sql/your_module_setup`
- name it `install-0.0.1.php`
- and add this to `config.xml`

  ```
  <resources>
      <your_module_setup>
          <setup>
              <module>Your_Module</module>
          </setup>
      </your_module_setup>
  </resources>
  ```

<sup>*Note: please check `core_resource` DB table too. If there is something related to this extension, delete it.*</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the links. I have doubt that is the install file that cannot run I think because I cannot see the table created (and I don't know if that affect the way to see in menu my extension). you think that I can attach it here o in github, you can see my install file in post. let me know. Thanks

Comment: I've click on flush Magento cache and I got the error, it was an error regarding addcolumn the "-" was missing you can see it in the code in the post. But when I try to enter to the extension I got the error that table doesn't exist and are not installed. does the install file is correct?

Comment: @javaTodev updated answer.